# share point server name change - all the sites are down

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm

we have installed sharepoint server 2013 on 2008 server machine and configured few sites. and after couple of days the server name has changed. (Eg: servername1 to servername2).

So when i go to database, the instance name changed to servername2 and IIS as well.

But when i run the sharepoint site url with latest servername it saying error in database. please configure from sharepoint products. then i tried to launch configure the existing server farm with latest sql server instance and database as server_config db but it saying not able to proceed.

could you please help me on this because we do not want to loose the sites which we configured previously.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the name back (if possible) and the then research the right way to change the server name on an existing SharePoint Farm. That way you get your sites back online while you figure it out.

Here is a link:

http://aanikin.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/how-to-rename-sharepoint-2010-server/

There is an stsadm command

stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername  -newservername

and there is also PowerShell command listed in that article.

Comment: I have renamed the server back to original name(servername1) and ran share point product wizard for existing farm then its worked well for me. you should enter passpharse password in order to revoke the sites.